# "Type "()" does not conform to protocol "SequenceType""

Tags: arrays, swift2

I am following an online class but my professor is using a different version of Xcode. I have version 7.2.1. It asked me to put parentheses after arr in the second line, but when I do, it says "Type "()" does not conform to protocol `SequenceType`. I don't know how to fix it. Thanks.

```
var arr = {1; 2; 3; 4}    
for i in arr() {    
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: What where you expecting to accomplish with `arr()`?

Comment: Seeing 3 major syntax errors in two lines I recommend to go for a better course.

Comment: @vadian you are right! So or so, "error: function 'arr' was used as a property; add () to call it" inside for-in loop which iterate ONLY over a sequence, is not very useful message, is it?

Comment: Actually `arr` is no sequence when enclosed in braces and separated by semicolons rather than square brackets and commas. @user3441734

Comment: @vadian exactly, so message like "error: arr does not conform to protocol SequenceType" could reflect the trouble much more better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array declaration needs to use brackets and commas.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in arr {
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write the same way is using below:-

**half-open range operator (..<)**

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in 0..<arr.count 
{
 print(arr[i])
}
```

**closed range operator (...)**

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in 0...arr.count-1 
{
 print(arr[i])
}
```

Comment: this syntax will NOT be available in the next Swift version, see swift.org for further details and explanation

Comment: Thanks for the link. But sorry could not find the documentation where they have mentioned that this for loop syntax will not be available in the next swift version?

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md

Comment: Have updated the answer. Please let me know if this is also not available in next Swift version 3.0??

Comment: Range is sequence, and for-in loop is designed to work over elements of sequence. i don't see any trouble ... why do you ask?

Comment: Thanks, was just confirming:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105939/discussion-between-user3441734-and-hussain-shabbir).